# How to determine the value of $x_0$ for which $\lim_{\chi \to x_0} f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm solving a certain problem for which I am trying to find the solution to the following equation:

$$c=\frac{4\exp{\frac{2Kl}{\delta K+L-e^\chi_s}}}{\delta(\exp{\frac{4Kl}{\delta K+L-e^\chi_s}}-1)}$$

Where $c = 0$, $\chi$ is the variable and the rest are constants. This function is undefined at $0$ but it has a value for the limit which can be solved numerically. If possible, I would like to have an expression for this value.

So basically I am looking for the value of $x_0$ for which the following relation holds

$$\lim_{\chi \to x_0}\frac{4\exp{\frac{2Kl}{\delta K+L-e^\chi_s}}}{\delta(\exp{\frac{4Kl}{\delta K+L-e^\chi_s}}-1)}=0$$

Any response would be very helpful.

Comment: So you're sending $c \to 0$? If that is what you want, you need $\frac{4Kl}{\delta K + L - e_s^\chi} \gg \frac{2Kl}{\delta K + L - e_s^\chi}$ which is just $\frac{Kl}{\delta K + L - e_s^\chi} \gg 1$, which will occur as the denominator goes to zero (from the right, assuming $Kl>0$), so I guess the limit you want is $\chi \to \log_{e_s}(\delta K + L)^-$.

Comment: I don't understand your second step, where you reduce the equation to just $\frac{Kl}{\delta K+L-e^{\chi}}$. I checked your answer with the numerical solution and its indeed correct. Thanks!

Comment: What matters is the difference of the two sides, since you're taking the ratio of the exponentials. That difference is $\frac{2Kl}{\delta K + L - e_s^\chi}$, so it is large and positive when the denominator goes to $0^+$ (assuming $Kl>0$ as I said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have that ratio go to zero, the only way is for the bottom exponential to be much larger than the top exponential. This means the difference of the arguments i.e. $\frac{-2Kl}{\delta K + L - e^\chi_s}$ has to go to $-\infty$. Assuming the parameters are positive, that means the denominator needs to go to zero from the right, which means $\chi$ needs to go to $\log_{e_s}(\delta K + L)$ from the left.